# Sense proximity to certain div

Tags: jquery

I was wondering with jQuery is it possible to have a div. then the closer you get to it move a certain amount up, so using CSS "top". Is it possible with jquery to sense the mouse position to the  with my image. I would use it here: http://ryancoughlin.com/hp/index.php - the spider in the top left.

What would I look in to for that? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

use javascript to capture mousemove, get the x and y co-ords, then use the distance formula to determine closest line to the div.